# Змейка на pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Есть код змейки:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np

def main_loop(): 
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (200, 200, 200)
    GREEN = (141, 182, 0)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    WIDTH = 20
    HEIGHT = 20
    
    MARGIN = 5
    
    grid = []
    snake_tails = []

    for row in range(11):

        grid.append([])
        for column in range(11):
            grid[row].append(0) 
    
    r = 5
    c = 5
    grid[c][r] = 1

    coord = (5, 6)

    for i in range(3):
        snake_tails.append([coord[0], coord[1] + i])
    # print(snake_tails)
    pygame.init()
    

    WINDOW_SIZE = [280, 280]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
    

    pygame.display.set_caption("Array Backed Grid")
    

    done = False

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    

    while not done:
        for i in pygame.event.get(): 
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:  
                done = True

            elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    grid[c + 2][r + 2] = 0
                    print((c, r))
                    r -= 1
                    grid[c][r] = 1

                elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    grid[c - 2][r - 2] = 0
                    r += 1
                    grid[c][r] = 1

                elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    grid[c - 2][r + 2] = 0
                    c += 1
                    grid[c][r] = 1

                elif i.key == pygame.K_UP:

                    grid[c + 2][r - 2] = 0

                    c -= 1
                    grid[c][r] = 1       



        # try:                
        #     keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #     if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        #         c1 = c + 2
        #         grid[c1][r + 2] = 0
                
        #         r -= 1
        #         grid[c][r] = 1

        #     elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:

        #         grid[c][r - 2] = 0
        #         r += 1
        #         grid[c][r] = 1

        #     elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:

        #         grid[c - 2][r] = 0
        #         c += 1
        #         grid[c][r] = 1

        #     elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        #         grid[c + 2][r] = 0
        #         c -= 1
        #         grid[c][r] = 1                        
        # except:
        #     main_loop()

        
        
        for i in grid:
            for j in i:
                if j == 1:
                    coord = (grid.index(i) ,i.index(j))
        
        #draw snake tails
        ltx = coord[1]
        lty = coord[0]

        for i, v in enumerate(snake_tails):
            _ltx = snake_tails[i][0]
            _lty = snake_tails[i][1]

            snake_tails[i][0] = ltx
            snake_tails[i][1] = lty

            ltx = _ltx
            lty = _lty

        for t in snake_tails:
            grid[t[1]][t[0]] = 1

        
        for row in range(11):
            for column in range(11):
                color = WHITE
                if grid[row][column] == 1:
                    color = GREEN
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                                color,
                                [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                                (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                                WIDTH,
                                HEIGHT])
    

        clock.tick(15)
        pygame.display.update()
        # screen.fill(WHITE)
    
    pygame.quit()

main_loop()
```

Змейка состоит из 3 элементов. Она должна двигаться по сетке, но вот что происходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grid[c][r] = 1
```

Вы красите сетку вместо модификации змейки(`snake_tails`)

Судя по коду, перед:

```
    for t in snake_tails:
        grid[t[1]][t[0]] = 1
```

Нужно очистить `grid` от старых данных, заполнить нулями, например.

Comment: Массив grid итак заполнене нулями, пустые клетки - это 0, если встречается 1 - это змейка

Comment: Да я понял. Только при обработке клавиатуры, надо не клетки перекрашивать, а просто поменять скорость змейки(направление). Потом она поменяется и сама перерисуется. Заполнять нулями надо на **каждой** итерации. Иначе весь старый мусор(единицы) так и будет зелёным.

Comment: А как менять направление?

Comment: сохраняете числа, h=-1 v=0 значит змейка поедет влево) При модификации змейки добавляете к голове клетку(x+h, y+v), убиваете элемент хвоста)

Comment: Можете, если несложно, показать это в коде, я что-то туплю

Comment: Вот подредактировал ваш код чуть: https://pastebin.com/t7n0ni26

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: У меня проблема, можете помочь?

Comment: Когда змейка выходит за границу экрана, она появляется в противоположной стороне. Как это исправить?

Comment: Если вопрос в том, как это реализовать - `new_segment = [(head[0]+v) % SIZE, (head[1]+h) % SIZE]`. В моей редакции кода этого поведения не было.